# How to get the list and dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I'm using streamlit to show my dataframe results.

I've this code to select the markets and timeframes by market.values() and timeframes.values()

```
timeframes = {
            'daily':'Daily',
            'weekly':'Weekly',
            'monthly':'Monthly',
            'quarterly':'Quarterly',
            'annually':'Annually'
        }    
markets = {
                'forex':{'Market':'Forex','Symbol':'EURUSD=X.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
                'crypto':{'Market':'Crypto','Symbol':'BTC-USD.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
                'futures':{'Market':'Futures','Symbol':'CL=F.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
                'indexes':{'Market':'Indexes','Symbol':'^NDX.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
                'etfs':{'Market':'ETFs','Symbol':'SPY.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
                'australia':{'Market':'Australian Stocks','Symbol':'BHP.AX.csv','Continent':'Oceania','Currency':'AUD'},
                'canada':{'Market':'Canadian Stocks','Symbol':'RY.TO.csv','Continent':'North America','Currency':'CAD'},
                'china':{'Market':'Chinese Stocks','Symbol':'600519.SS.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'CNY'},
                'france':{'Market':'French Stocks','Symbol':'MC.PA.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
                'germany':{'Market':'German Stocks','Symbol':'SAP.DE.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
                'hongkong':{'Market':'Hong Kong Stocks','Symbol':'0941.HK.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'HKD'},
                'india':{'Market':'Indian Stocks','Symbol':'RELIANCE.NS.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'INR'},
                'italy':{'Market':'Italian Stocks','Symbol':'RACE.MI.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
                'japan':{'Market':'Japanese Stocks','Symbol':'7203.T.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'JPY'},
                'singapore':{'Market':'Singapore Stocks','Symbol':'D05.SI.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'SGD'},
                'spain':{'Market':'Spanish Stocks','Symbol':'ITX.MC.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
                'swiss':{'Market':'Swiss Stocks','Symbol':'NESN.SW.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'CHF'},
                'unitedarabemirates':{'Market':'UAE Stocks','Symbol':'DEWA.AE.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'AED'},
                'unitedkingdom':{'Market':'UK Stocks','Symbol':'AZN.L.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'GBP'},
                'unitedstates':{'Market':'US Stocks','Symbol':'AAPL.csv','Continent':'North America','Currency':'USD'},
                'test':{'Market':'Test','Symbol':'AAPL.csv','Continent':'North America','Currency':'USD'}
            }    
selected_markets = st.multiselect(label='Market',options=list(markets.values()),default=list(markets.values()))
selected_timeframes = st.multiselect(label='Timeframe',options=list(timeframes.values()),default=list(timeframes.values()))
```

And then this code to read every market and timeframe data csv file selected.

```
for selected_market in selected_markets:
    for selected_timeframe in selected_timeframes:
        df = pd.read_csv('{}'.format("data/" + selected_market + "_" + selected_timeframe + ".csv"))
```

And I've a problem because the "selected_market" and "selected:timeframe" in the for loop for example is "Australian Stocks" and "Daily", and the file "Australian Stocks_Daily.csv" not exists, I've "australia_daily.csv" file.
I don't know how can refer the "selected_market" to key in the "market" list and "selected_timeframe" to key in the "timeframes" list.

Any idea to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `.lower()` to convert the strings to lowercase.

Comment: You don't need to use `'{}'.format()`. The concatenation creates a string, you don't need to re-format it.

Comment: Why are you looping over the dataframes instead of the dictionaries? The dictionary keys are lowercase, which is what you want.

Comment: @Barmar I think streamlit is returning the selected market labels, as in `'Australian Stocks'` for `'Market': 'Australian Stocks'`. OP probably needs a *market label* -> *markets key* lookup dict.

Comment: Because "selected_markets" is provided by streamlit frontend, it can change by user, so I only need to read the files needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the code to use the keys from the markets and timeframes dictionaries when constructing the file path for reading the CSV files.

```
for selected_market in selected_markets:
for selected_timeframe in selected_timeframes:
    # Construct the filename using keys
    filename = "{}_{}.csv".format(markets[selected_market]['Symbol'], selected_timeframe.lower())
    file_path = os.path.join("data", filename)

    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        # Read the CSV file
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        # Process your dataframe as needed
    else:
        st.warning(f"File not found: {file_path}")
```

Comment: If Australia was selected, wouldn't your code try to open `"BHP.AX.csv_daily.csv"` and not `"australia_daily.csv"`? If it doesn't error, since `markets` doesn't have a `'Australian Stocks'` key.

Comment: The stock file is for other function in the same app. I need to read "australia_daily.csv" when the user select "Australian Stocks"

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup `dict`.

```python
markets_lookup = { val['Market']: key for key, val in markets.items()}

for selected_market in selected_markets:
    for selected_timeframe in selected_timeframes:
        key = markets_lookup[selected_market]
        df = pd.read_csv(f"data/{key}_{selected_timeframe.lower()}.csv"))
```

I'm unable to test this code, so let me know if there are any errors.

---

**Edit:**

```python
markets = {
    'forex':{'Market':'Forex','Symbol':'EURUSD=X.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
    'crypto':{'Market':'Crypto','Symbol':'BTC-USD.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
    'futures':{'Market':'Futures','Symbol':'CL=F.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
    'indexes':{'Market':'Indexes','Symbol':'^NDX.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
    'etfs':{'Market':'ETFs','Symbol':'SPY.csv','Continent':'World','Currency':'USD'},
    'australia':{'Market':'Australian Stocks','Symbol':'BHP.AX.csv','Continent':'Oceania','Currency':'AUD'},
    'canada':{'Market':'Canadian Stocks','Symbol':'RY.TO.csv','Continent':'North America','Currency':'CAD'},
    'china':{'Market':'Chinese Stocks','Symbol':'600519.SS.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'CNY'},
    'france':{'Market':'French Stocks','Symbol':'MC.PA.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
    'germany':{'Market':'German Stocks','Symbol':'SAP.DE.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
    'hongkong':{'Market':'Hong Kong Stocks','Symbol':'0941.HK.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'HKD'},
    'india':{'Market':'Indian Stocks','Symbol':'RELIANCE.NS.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'INR'},
    'italy':{'Market':'Italian Stocks','Symbol':'RACE.MI.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
    'japan':{'Market':'Japanese Stocks','Symbol':'7203.T.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'JPY'},
    'singapore':{'Market':'Singapore Stocks','Symbol':'D05.SI.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'SGD'},
    'spain':{'Market':'Spanish Stocks','Symbol':'ITX.MC.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'EUR'},
    'swiss':{'Market':'Swiss Stocks','Symbol':'NESN.SW.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'CHF'},
    'unitedarabemirates':{'Market':'UAE Stocks','Symbol':'DEWA.AE.csv','Continent':'Asia','Currency':'AED'},
    'unitedkingdom':{'Market':'UK Stocks','Symbol':'AZN.L.csv','Continent':'Europe','Currency':'GBP'},
    'unitedstates':{'Market':'US Stocks','Symbol':'AAPL.csv','Continent':'North America','Currency':'USD'},
    'test':{'Market':'Test','Symbol':'AAPL.csv','Continent':'North America','Currency':'USD'}
}

markets_lookup = {val['Market']: key for key, val in markets.items()}
print(markets_lookup)
```

Outputs:

```text
{'Forex': 'forex', 'Crypto': 'crypto', 'Futures': 'futures', 'Indexes': 'indexes', 'ETFs': 'etfs', 'Australian Stocks': 'australia', 'Canadian Stocks': 'canada', 'Chinese Stocks': 'china', 'French Stocks': 'france', 'German Stocks': 'germany', 'Hong Kong Stocks': 'hongkong', 'Indian Stocks': 'india', 'Italian Stocks': 'italy', 'Japanese Stocks': 'japan', 'Singapore Stocks': 'singapore', 'Spanish Stocks': 'spain', 'Swiss Stocks': 'swiss', 'UAE Stocks': 'unitedarabemirates', 'UK Stocks': 'unitedkingdom', 'US Stocks': 'unitedstates', 'Test': 'test'}
```

Comment: Thanks @jonny, I've this error "markets_lookup = { val['Market']: key for key, val in markets.items()}
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: I do not get that `TypeError` when I use `markets_lookup = {val['Market']: key for key, val in markets.items()}` with the `markets` dictionary you provided in your question.

Comment: I don't know why not runs in my app. I only different that I import this dictionary from another python file. But I use this dictionary in other parts in the same app.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `markets` is getting reassigned to some type of sequence (`list`, `tuple`, maybe a `dataframe`, etc.) before creating `markets_lookup`.